inequality involving factorials
Let $p>1$ be a positive integer and let $a_0,a_1$ be non-negative integers with $0\le a_0\le p-1$ and $1\le p\le a_1$. Show that
$$\prod_{b=1}^{a_1}\left(\frac{(a_0+bp)!}{a_0!b!}\right)^{{a_1\choose b}\frac{1}{p^b}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^{a_1-b}}\le \left(\frac{(a_0+a_1p)!}{a_0!a_1!}\right)^{1/p}.$$
Any idea of why this should be the case?

This expression askd for a probabilistic meaning. But why are you sure that this holds?

I am not sure that it holds: I only have a huge computational evidence. When $a_1=1$, the two sides are equal but data suggests that as $a_1$ gets larger,  the left hand side becomes smaller than the right hand side.

Then do not tell "show that", but like "huge computational evidence suggests that the following is true. Any ideas whether it is and if yes, how to prove it?" also motivation to study this question is highly welcome
